# How to show a users bio on a page

Tags: php, users, actions

I'm fairly new to Wordpress.  I have users that create profiles on my site and one of the sections is their bio.  How can I take this information and display it on lets say a "users profile page".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress already comes with the [`author`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) page/functionality.

Let's say you have the author `john` on your site `www.example.com`, then you'd see his author page at `www.example.com/author/john`.

If you want to customize this, you have to tweak (or maybe even create, depending on your theme) the `author.php` or other author template files.